# this.DataContext is NULL? Use to be filled - Switched to Autofac

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light, autofac, datacontext

I am using MVVM Light, Autofac for windows phone 7 and Autofac locator.

**With autofac**

http://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Wp7

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Ioc;
using Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation;
using MvvmLight1.Model;
using Autofac;

namespace MvvmLight1.ViewModel
{
    public class ViewModelLocator
    {
        static ViewModelLocator()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            builder.RegisterType<MainViewModel>();

            var container = builder.Build();
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new AutofacServiceLocator(container));
        }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance",
            "CA1822:MarkMembersAsStatic",
            Justification = "This non-static member is needed for data binding purposes.")]
        public MainViewModel Main
        {
            get
            {
                return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
            }
        }
    }
} 


using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

namespace MvvmLight1
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var main = this.DataContext as MainPage; // will be null
        }
    }
}

<phone:PhoneApplicationPage x:Class="MvvmLight1.MainPage"
                            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                            xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
                            xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
                            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                            xmlns:ignore="http://www.ignore.com"
                            mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
                            FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
                            FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
                            Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
                            SupportedOrientations="Portrait"
                            Orientation="Portrait"
                            d:DesignWidth="480"
                            d:DesignHeight="768"
                            shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
                            DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

    <!--LayoutRoot contains the root grid where all other page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
          Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Margin="24,24,0,12">
            <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle"
                       Text="{Binding ApplicationTitle}"
                       Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle"
                       Text="{Binding PageName}"
                       Margin="-3,-8,0,0"
                       Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}" />
        </StackPanel>

        <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid"
              Grid.Row="1">

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding WelcomeTitle}"
                       Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="40" 
                       TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                       TextAlignment="Center" />

        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>


using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Autofac;
using Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation;

namespace MvvmLight1
{
    public sealed class AutofacServiceLocator : ServiceLocatorImplBase
    {
        readonly IComponentContext _container;

        public AutofacServiceLocator(IComponentContext container)
        {
            if (container == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("container");
            _container = container;
        }

        protected override object DoGetInstance(Type serviceType, string key)
        {
            return key != null ? _container.ResolveNamed(key, serviceType) : _container.Resolve(serviceType);
        }

        protected override IEnumerable<object> DoGetAllInstances(Type serviceType)
        {
            var enumerableType = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(serviceType);

            object instance = _container.Resolve(enumerableType);
            return ((IEnumerable)instance).Cast<object>();
        }
    }
}


using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using MvvmLight1.Model;

namespace MvvmLight1.ViewModel
{
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

now the viewModel in my constructor of MainPage.cs will always be null.

When I just used SimpleIoc it was filled with the Main Object.

Comment: Exactly where (in which class's which method) do you have this line `ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(...` in your solution?

Comment: It's in my Locator Class, I updated my code.

Comment: Only the `ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider` what you have changed? So the `loginVm = this.DataContext as LoginVm;` always was in the `LoginView` constructor and the `DataContext` always was set with `DataContext="{Binding Login, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"`? How and where do you crate your `LoginView`?

Comment: By the way why do you want hold a reference to your `LoginVm` inside your view's constructor?

Comment: From which library this `AutofacServiceLocator` is coming from? Of if it is custom type please post the code of it!

Comment: Yes only the ViewModel Locator class has changed. I changed it from SimpleIoc to Autofac. Everything else should be the same. I need a property from the LoginVm in my codebehind. I could probably rearrange the code better but don't want to at this time and want to know why it does not work.

Comment: I cannot repro your issue. In a newly created project it is working fine with the SimpleIoC and also with Autofac. The `DataContext` is not null in my views constructor... How and where do you create your `LoginVm`? Are you using `NavigationService.Navigate` to display it or something else?

Comment: I can only repro it if the registration is not complate and Autofac throws an exception... do you also get an exceptoin? You may need to turn stopping of exceptions on in Visual Studio: Debug > Excpetions... and make sure that both checkbox is checked in the second line: Common Language Runtime Exceptions. Can you also post your `LoginVm` constructor?

Comment: Ya I get the exception, I rewrote my OP using all the default Names and showed all the code. Weird thing is now SimpleIoc is not working either. left all the default code that it makes and get null for Main in my codebehind of MainPg.

Comment: I guess you still have a typo in your post `this.DataContext as MainPage;` should be `this.DataContext as MainViewModel;`.. never the less you can try to move the `DataContext` setting from the XAML to the code behind to more esaily track down the problem. So remove `DataContext="{Binding Main, ` from your XAML. And add this line in the `MainPage` constructor : `InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = ((ViewModelLocator) Application.Current.Resources["Locator"]).Main;
            vm = DataContext as MainViewModel;`